# In android, how to apply scale animation so that the scaled image appears on top of everything else?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation, android-linearlayout

I'm applying a scale animation to a view (a grid item), which is in a gridview, which is in a pager, which is in a linear layout.

Everything already works besides my scaled griditem becomes larger than the gridview / pager, and it's clipped (or hidden? by siblings of the pager). I tried putting android:clipChildren="false"
    android:clipToPadding="false" everywhere where there's a parent view and it's supported (in the linear layout and in the grid view), but had no effect.

I also tried calling bringToFront() on the pager, but this also doesn't work, still get clipped and besides of that causes repositions the pager at the bottom of the layout, which is unwanted.

How do I play the animation in front of everything?[Here the 1st image on the second row is scaled but it gets clipped instead of appearing on top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1aQl.png)

here is the xml code for animation:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <scale
        android:duration="200"
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:toXScale="2.0"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="2.0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
      />
</set>
```

Here is the xml code for buttons:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:weightSum="4">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/im11"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/munshee_logo"
            android:padding="1dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:cropToPadding="true"
            android:background="@drawable/munshee_logo"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/im12"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="1dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:cropToPadding="true"
            android:background="@drawable/munshee_logo"

            android:src="@drawable/munshee_logo" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/im13"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="1dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:cropToPadding="true"
            android:background="@drawable/munshee_logo"
            android:src="@drawable/munshee_logo" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/im14"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="1dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:cropToPadding="true"
            android:background="@drawable/munshee_logo"
            android:src="@drawable/munshee_logo" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:weightSum="4">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/im21"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="1dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:cropToPadding="true"
            android:background="@drawable/munshee_logo"
            android:src="@drawable/munshee_logo" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/im22"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="1dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:cropToPadding="true"
            android:background="@drawable/munshee_logo"
            android:src="@drawable/munshee_logo" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/im23"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="1dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:cropToPadding="true"
            android:background="@drawable/munshee_logo"
            android:src="@drawable/munshee_logo" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/im24"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="1dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:cropToPadding="true"
            android:background="@drawable/munshee_logo"
            android:src="@drawable/munshee_logo" />

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout8"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:weightSum="4">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/im81"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="1dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:cropToPadding="true"
            android:background="@drawable/munshee_logo"
            android:src="@drawable/munshee_logo" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/im82"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="1dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:cropToPadding="true"
            android:background="@drawable/munshee_logo"
            android:src="@drawable/munshee_logo" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/im83"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="1dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:cropToPadding="true"
            android:background="@drawable/munshee_logo"
            android:src="@drawable/munshee_logo" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/im84"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="1dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:cropToPadding="true"
            android:background="@drawable/munshee_logo"
            android:src="@drawable/munshee_logo" />


    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the java code:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_demo2);
        final Animation bounce1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.bounce);
        bounce1.setFillAfter(true);
        final Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.im21);
        button1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    v.startAnimation(bounce1);

                    return true;
                }
                else if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){

                    v.clearAnimation();
                    return false;
                }
                return false;
            }

        });
```

Comment: It appears to be a case of clipping from parent. I'd suggest you retry the `clipChildren=false` approach (mainly because it is needed in any case) and then if it doesn't work share the xml

Comment: It disables the clipping but the scaled view appears on top of the left and top image and goes under the right and bottom image. I want it to appear on top of everything including right and bottom.

Comment: You're going to have a hard time doing that with LinearLayouts. The z-order affects the order they are drawn and their position.